# What do I need to project my Windows 10 PC screen on my HDTV?

Tags: windows-10, screen-sharing, miracast

I'm trying to project my PC screen on to my new UHD TV.  I would prefer doing it over the LAN but wirelessly is OK.  Here's what I've got

- a brand new UHD TV that natively supports Miracast.  (LG OLED65C7P)
- a 2-year-old Dell Precision 1700 Windows 10 PC with an Intel Chipset that is
  supposed to support Miracast  (4600 chipset).
- My PC has no built-in Wifi.  I have a Verizon Fios Quantum Gateway 1100 Router for that
- The very latest OS updates available and the very latest drivers I can find installed.  I've gone through both Windows Update and Dell's "Precision Optimizer"
- both a wifi *and* a physical LAN connection from the PC to the TV.

Although my TV is able and ready to accept Miracast connections, My PC is not. 
 After setting up the TV to Miracast mode, when I go to my PC and attempt to connect, Windows tells me "Your PC or mobile device does not support Miracast so it can't project wirelessly."

MY Windows PC is clearly lacking some piece of hardware or software to make this happen.  Can someone tell me what that would be?

I just want to be able to show my live PC Screen on the TV.  I would prefer doing it over the wired connection but I'm fine doing it wirelessly as well.

Comment: I am pretty sure Miracast only works over a wireless connection.  I am not sure how you are using a router as a wireless adapter to connect to the routers access point

Comment: If you *want* to do it using a wire, why not an HDMI? Or whatever other connections your PC supports.  The tv likely only has HDMI inputs.  So either an HDMI to HDMI cable or display port to HDMI should do.

Comment: miracast is wireless only.

Comment: Thanks.   I do realize miracast is wireless only.    I should clarify that my PC is wired into the router and the TV wirelessly connects to that.  That apparently is enough for my TV to see both the internet and my PC.  And now that I have run an Ethernet cable from the router, the TV is now physically connected to it as well.  Seems odd that there is a wireless solution (Miracast) yet no wired option.  

However if Miracast is the way to go, then I am concerned that my PC itself says it cannot project over Miracast.  I am wondering what it lacks to make it think it can.  A WIFI Card?

Comment: You can use a Miracast Video Adapter like this one from Belkin: http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F7D7501/

Comment: I appreciate the answer but again, isn't that adapter for TVs that do not support Miracast?  My TV does support Miracast.  It is my PC that does not.

Answer (score 1):

I find that miracast tends to be finniky, easy solution is to use a microsoft wireless display adapter.

> https://www.scorptec.com.au/product/Notebooks/Accessories/64606-P3Q-00016?gclid=CjwKCAiA07PRBRBJEiwAS20SIC5CDB2CPCJFMPn-P7iKJy65z7Z2q_dSFNpfUUb5ABmtDVQSsSutQxoCXw8QAvD_BwE

I've set up a few and though they aren't the be all and end all (a hdmi cable is just so simple) for wireless in windows 10 it works well. probably get cheaper elsewhere, link is just for example.

Comment: But isn't that something that you plug into the TV?  As it is my PC reporting that it does not support projecting wirelessly, wouldn't this thing leave me in the same situation?

The TV itself is already to go with Miracast.  It even has a dedicated screen for it.  I thought the MS Wireless Display Adapter was just for TVs that were not ready for this?

Comment: As far as i am aware they are separate technologies. The MS WDA is for the TV end but the crucial difference is the network connectivity is simpler as they only need to be on the same network, having your computer using a wired connection to the network and the MS WDA using a wireless connection to the same network, they will still be able to see one another and connect. Miracast on the other hand is a direct wireless connection Protocol between streaming device and wireless display.

Comment: The Three alternatives to my above suggestion:1/ If using google chrome, use a Chromecast, setup is really easy and works on a similar principle where the two devices only need to share a network. 2/ If Miracast is a requirement for you, then i would recommend upgrading your laptop to include a Wireless Network card (a USB wireless network adaptor can be had for as little as $10) or finally, if you don't really want to buy anything then you can of course run a HDMI cable from your laptop to your TV.